# Утечка памяти в методе? (с++)

Tags: c++

Привожу код перегруженного метода (некое подобие срезов) в котором происходит утечка памяти. Помогите пожалуйста найти где именно. Локальная переменная temp должна же уничтожаться?
Почему функция не работает при присваивании temp.size=0 и работает при 11..1?
Поле класса size используется для остлеживания статуса вызова метода. (В случае если это уже второй вызов метода размер строки не будет совпадать с полем size.)

```
struct String 
{
    String(const char *str = "")
    {
        this->size=strlen(str);
        this->str=new char [size+1];
        for(int i=0; i < this->size; i++)
            this->str[i]=str[i];
        this->str[size]='\0';
    }
    ~String()
    {
        delete [] str;
    }
    String(const String &other)
    {
        this->size=other.size;
        this->str=new char [size+1];
        for (int i=0; i<=this->size; i++)
            this->str[i]=other.str[i];
    }
    String& operator=(const String &other)
    {
        this->~String();
        this->size=other.size;
        this->str=new char [size];
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
            this->str[i]=other.str[i];
        return *this;
    }

    String operator[](const int ii) const
    {
        String temp;
        if (this->size == strlen(this->str)) {
            if (ii != 0)
                temp.size = this->size;
            else
                temp.size=111111;
            temp.str = new char[this->size - ii];
            for (int i = ii; i < this->size; i++)
                temp.str[i - ii] = this->str[i];
        } else
        {
            if (this->size==111111) temp.size=ii;
            else temp.size=strlen(this->str)+ii-this->size;
            temp.str=new char [temp.size];
            for (int i=0; i<temp.size; i++)
            temp.str[i]=this->str[i];
        }
        return temp;
    }

    public:
        size_t size;
        char *str;
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream & os, const String &a)
{
    os << a.str;
    return os;
}

int main() {
    String a;
    a=String("asdasd");
    String b=a[2][3];
    b=a[0][2];
    cout << b << endl;
    String const hello("hello");
    String const hell = hello[0][4]; // теперь в hell хранится подстрока "hell"
    String const ell  = hello[1][4]; // теперь в ell хранится подстрока "ell"
    cout << hello << " " << hello.size << endl;
    cout << hell << " " << hell.size << endl;
    cout << ell << " " << ell.size << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Есть new - нет delete - утечка памяти.

Comment: Разве после закрывающей скобки не должен вызваться деструктор класса? ~String(){ delete [] str;}

Comment: А покажите деструктор класса `String`.

Comment: ~String()  { delete [] str; }

Comment: Похоже, у Вашего класса String нет конструктора копирования/перемещения. А поэтому, вызывая деструктор, Вы удаляете строку внутри. А в вызывающий код прибежит указатель на удаленную память.

Answer (score 1):

Ваши конструкторы содержат явные ошибки. Для начала - они не эквивалентны. То есть, они будут создавать разные объекты.

конструктор копирования выделят достаточно места, но забывает о нулевом символе в конце

```
String(const String &other)
{
    this->size=other.size;
    this->str=new char [size+1];
    for (int i=0; i<=this->size; i++)
        this->str[i]=other.str[i];
    this->str[this->size] = '\0';
}
```

Но можно и короче написать, если уже пишете в си стиле.

```
String(const String &other)
{
    this->size=other.size;
    this->str=new char [size+1];
    strncmp(this->str, other.str, other.size);
    this->str[this->size] = '\0';
}
```

Вызов деструктора в `operator=` это интересно:) я бы писал как минимум так.

```
String& operator=(const String &other)
{
    delete[] this->str;
    this->size=other.size;
    this->str=new char [size+1];
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
        this->str[i]=other.str[i];
    this->str[this->size] = '\0';
    return *this;
}
```

**UPD**

Минимально поправил код, что бы убрать утечки (хотя их то и не было) и всевозможные расстрелы памяти.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

struct String 
{
    String(const char *str = "")
    {
        this->size=strlen(str);
        this->str=new char [size+1];
        for(int i=0; i < this->size; i++)
            this->str[i]=str[i];
        this->str[size]='\0';
    }
    ~String()
    {
        delete [] str;
    }
    String(const String &other)
    {
        this->size=other.size;
        this->str=new char [size+1];
        for (int i=0; i<=this->size; i++)
            this->str[i]=other.str[i];
        this->str[size] = '\0';
    }
    String& operator=(const String &other)
    {
        delete[] this->str;
        this->size=other.size;
        this->str=new char [size+1];
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
            this->str[i]=other.str[i];
        this->str[size] = '\0';
        return *this;
    }

    String operator[](const int ii) const
    {
        String temp;
        if (this->size == strlen(this->str)) {
            if (ii != 0)
                temp.size = this->size;
            else
                temp.size=111111;
            delete[] temp.str;
            temp.str = new char[this->size - ii+1];
            for (int i = ii; i < this->size; i++)
                temp.str[i - ii] = this->str[i];
            temp.str[this->size - ii] = '\0';
        } else
        {
            if (this->size==111111) temp.size=ii;
            else temp.size=strlen(this->str)+ii-this->size;
            delete[] temp.str;
            temp.str=new char [temp.size+1];
            for (int i=0; i<temp.size; i++)
                temp.str[i]=this->str[i];
            temp.str[temp.size] = '\0';
        }
        return temp;
    }

    public:
        size_t size;
        char *str;
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream & os, const String &a)
{
    os << a.str;
    return os;
}

int main() {
    String a;
    a=String("asdasd");
    String b=a[2][3];
    b=a[0][2];
    cout << b << endl;
    String const hello("hello");
    String const hell = hello[0][4]; // теперь в hell хранится подстрока "hell"
    String const ell  = hello[1][4]; // теперь в ell хранится подстрока "ell"
    cout << hello << " " << hello.size << endl;
    cout << hell << " " << hell.size << endl;
    cout << ell << " " << ell.size << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

правда, что длает `size = 111111` я так и не понял. Это похоже на жуткий костыль.

P.S. пока смотрел на код, понял, что я уже видел этот код на ru.stackoverflow.com. И даже исправлял подобные ошибки.

Comment: Спасибо, поправил, несколько раз менял код и не заметил что намудрил. Но утечка именно в методе operator[]. Хотел уточнить также с operator=, почему не стоит деструктор вызывать? Логично же было бы переменную освободить, если мы ей присваиваем другое значение?

Comment: если Вы подозреваете, что есть утечка памяти, создайте минимальный пример, который воспроизводит пробелу и выложите полный код.

Comment: это учебное задание по курсу в котором необходимо реализовать только оператор []. есть несколько обходных и более простых путей решения задачи с использованием дополнительных классов. Но в дискуссиях преподаватели говорили о том, что это не очень хороший способ, потому и хочется победить утечку, чтобы разобраться в вопросе более основательно. Код привел.

Comment: Учебный курс [этот](https://stepic.org/lesson/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-559/step/9) ?

Comment: Да, курс этот. Утечка все равно осталась.

Comment: В коде выше утечек уже нет. Покажите код, который воспроизводит утечку или расскажите, как Вы ее определяете.

Comment: На данную задачу написаны тесты авторами курса и они их не публикуют. При попытки сдачи выдается сообщение об утечке: Memory leaks

Comment: По поводу size = 11111 это костыль, я пробовал присваивать значение равное 0, что более логично, но почему-то в этом случае не работает код при передаче первым аргументов 0 - hello[0][4]. Пробовал искать ошибку, в тот момент и исправил на произвольное число... (все заработало)

Comment: Нашел припрятанную утечку. Теперь ее нет. Вот только сертификат об окончании учебы кому будете отдавать?:)

Comment: Спасибо. Не знаю кто как, а я обычно за знаниями прихожу на курсы. И именно потому настроен решать задачи правильно, а не использовать хаки. Теперь кстати в решении можно и нормально условие написать, не работало из-за мусора - вместо 11111 поставить 0 :)

Comment: По поводу `operator=`: а теперь представьте, что будет, если написать `string = string;`

Comment: не совсем понимаю о каком вызове метода идет речь, можно подробнее описать что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: Наверное, @Roman имел ввиду, что необходимо запретить самоприсваивание в operator=

Comment: `if (this == &other) {
     return *this;
 } `